# Using Green's formula for a vector field in a planar point set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I am trying to calculate the integral of the vector field $F = \begin{bmatrix}-y & x\end{bmatrix}^T$ in the point set $S = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4\}$ in two ways with Green's formula. Currently I am having both computational and conceptual issues.

The computational issue to which I ran into is that if I am not mistaken, $\int\int_S(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y})dA = \int_1^2\int_1^{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}2dydx = \int_1^2\sqrt{4 - x^2} - 1dx$. From this I don't really see any other way forward than to substitute $x = 2\sin(u)$ and recalculate the limits. Is this really the only way forward, or is there a better trick to this?

The conceptual issue I am having is that how do even start to compute the boundary integral? Sure, $\partial S = C_1 \cup C_4$, where $C_1 = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ and $C_4 = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 4\}$. How can I parametrize $\partial S$? I am bit rusty with path integrals, so does it hold that $\int_{\partial S}F_1 dx + F_2 dy = (\int_{C_1}F_1 dx + F_2 dy) + (\int_{C_4}F_1 dx + F_2 dy)$?

Edit: The question I am solving is that *Calculate the integrals of Green's theorem w.r.t vectorfield $F$ and pointset $S$*.

Comment: The bounds for the integral are incorrect. Also if $C$ is the boundary of the region between two circles, you can convert it into a simply connected and piece-wise smooth region to apply Green's theorem. But first, can you type in exactly what the question says?

Comment: @MathLover See edit for the question. Could you explain why the bounds are incorrect? My reasoning was that $x$ can go from $1$ to $2$, and hence $y$ can go from $1$ to $\sqrt{4 - x^2}$, as $1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$.

How can I convert the boundary to the region you mentioned? Change of coordinates? Subtraction of parametrized curves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bounds for the region is not correct. The region is the area between two circles $x^2+y2 = 1$ and $x^2+y^2 = 4$. If you do it in cartesian coordinates, you will have to split your integral. It is easier to do it in polar coordinates, the limits should be $1 \leq r \leq 2, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ and $dA = r \ dr \ d\theta$.

As far as the question, I think it could be written more clearly.

To apply Green's Theorem, the curve has to be positively oriented, piecewise smooth, simple and closed.

So if we define curve $C$ as going from point $A$ along $C_1$ in anti-clockwise direction to point $B$ and then to point $C$, along $C_2$ in clockwise direction (region continues to be on your left) back to point $C$, then to point $B$ and then along $C_1$ in anticlockwise direction back to point $A$, we have a region that meets all the conditions we spoke about earlier to apply Green's theorem.

[image]

When we are doing line integral, note that the line integral along $BC$ and $CB$ will cancel out.

So the line integral along $C$ is equivalent to line integral along $C_1 \cup C_2$ where $C_1$ is anti-clockwise along $r = 2$ and $C_2$ is clockwise along $r = 1$.

You can parametrize $C_1$ as $(2 \cos t, 2 \sin t), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ and $C_2$ as $(\cos t, \sin t), 2\pi \leq t \leq 0$.

Comment: Few more questions: Firstly, usually at this point one points out that $BC$ and $CB$ cancel each other out, and then only focus on $C_1$ and $C_2$. This makes sense, but what would be the expression of the parametrization for the entire curve? Or does piecewise parametrization mean that we express the parametrization for each part, and that's that? Also, I am sorry if this may sound like harping, but is $\int_{\partial S}F_1 dx + F_2 dy = \sum_{C \in P}\int_C F_1 dx + F_2 dy$, where $P$ contains the parametrized parts of $S$?

Lastly, how would you refactor the question?

Comment: $BC$ is a straight line so it will get parametrized differently. The parametrization will be piecewise here. You basically define $C$ as $C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3 \cup (-C_3)$ where $C_1 = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t), 0$ to $2\pi$ and so on.

Comment: $\iint_{\partial S} (\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}) \ dA = \int_C F_1 \ dx + F_2 \ dy, \ C = C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3 \cup (-C_3)$

Comment: So then, is it true that: $\int_CF_1 dx + F_2 dy = \int_{C_1}F_1 dx + F_2 dy + \int_{C_2}F_1 dx + F_2 dy + ... + \int_{-C_3}F_1 dx + F_2 dy$?

Comment: Yes that is true.